# How can I display "No results Match that criteria" after a list has been filtered?

Tags: jquery, html, filtering

So I have created a pretty simple filtering navigation for a list, see the JS fiddle

As you can see there is an option number six, however there is no criteria for number six.

So when "FILTER SIX" is clicked the current list appears blank.

However I would like a message to appear something like "No Results Match That Criteria."

http://jsfiddle.net/H9Gj3/

```
$('#filterOptions div').click(function () {
    // fetch the class of the clicked item
    var ourDataAttr = $(this).data('name');
    // reset the active class on all the buttons
    $('#filterOptions div').removeClass('active');
    // update the active state on our clicked button
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if (ourDataAttr == 'all') {
        // show all our items
        $('#content').find('.item').fadeIn(500);
    } 
    else {
        // hdatee all elements that don't share ourClass
        $('#content').find('.item:not([data-name="' + ourDataAttr + '"])').fadeOut(500);
        // show all elements that do share ourClass
        $('#content').find('.item[data-name="' + ourDataAttr + '"]').fadeIn(500);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: after `$('#content').find('.item[data-name="' + ourDataAttr + '"]').fadeIn(500);`

add a class like "displayed", then `$(".displayed").length` gives you the count of shown elements...if that is 0, you can show the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H9Gj3/7/

mines basically like @hari execpt i add/remove the message to the content div using

```
    if($('#content').find('.item[data-name="' + ourDataAttr + '"]').length == 0){
            $('#content').append('<li class="no-item">No Results Match That Criteria.</li>');
    }else $('.no-item').remove();
```

Comment: Works a treat however, if there are two fliters that have no criteria it double appends the li class of no-item :\ NEVERMIND
i just popped in $(".no-item").remove(); when each filter is clicked. sorted.

Answer (score 0):

take value when fadein happen `fadein`.check length,highlight your error message.

```
        var x= $('#content').find('.item[data-name="' + ourDataAttr + '"]').fadeIn(500);
        if(x.length==0){
        alert('No Results Match That Criteria.');
        }
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H9Gj3/5/)